# synergy: how to switch language on client

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, synergy

I use [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/ru/) to share single keyboard and mouse and clipboard on 2 computers. Server and Client computers run **windows 7 x64 ultimate**. On client computer I got 2 languages English and Russian. When I triing to change language on client computer to Russian, I see that language icon changed to Russian. But when I starting typing I see that language icon **turn back to English** and I see english characters. When I triing to switch language **by mouse** - the same result. When I triing to switch language using **client keyboard or mouse** on the client I got the same result. So how can I switch language on the client?

Strange behavior: when I pressed Alt-Shift the language turned to Russian. And now I can't switch it to English.

Solution **found**:
To switch language on client you need to point your mouse on server and turn language there. The language of client is **defined by language on server**.

Comment: Have you tried switching the language using the Alt+Shift shortcut?

Comment: @StefanSeidel yes I tried

Answer (score -1):

After an hour of torment with Synergy, I stumbled on an alternative solution - [ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/download.php) tool - that solved the problem with language switching for me. The [free](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/docs2/09/shop.php) version of this app has the same features as Synergy plus ability to switch between screens by a shortcut.