# how to write in other languages in synergy?

Tags: windows-7, synergy

I need to write in Persian on other computer that I controlling with synergy. 
but when I change the language , and start typing , its changed to English and not to work on other language . 
server is 64bit ultimate version of windows 7 , and the client is professional. 
thanks for helping.

Comment: Though not a dupe, [the related question](http://superuser.com/questions/547941/synergy-how-to-switch-language-on-client) seems useful to the OP.